# How to add header column in excel using Java Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing a java program in which I have to take data from XML file and put it into excel file. While doing this I have to create row headers and add data accordingly.

I know how to create column headers. I can do it in following way:

```
....
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("EDR Raw Data");

    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Header1");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Header2");
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Header3");
    header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Header4");
....
```

It creates excel file as shown below:
[image]

But I want my excel file looks like below:

[image]

I am not getting a way to do this. It's not good idea to create required number of rows individually. Is there any way by which we can create a column and add all header in that column?

The way I tried to do this is:

```
....
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("EDR Raw Data");

sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("header1");
sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue("header2");
sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellValue("header3");
sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0).setCellValue("header4");
...
```

But in my case I have to give 100+ row labels. SO this won't be efficient way.

Comment: A spreadsheet in HSSF/XSSF is organized in workbooks, each workbook is organized in rows, each row contains individual cells. While you think that it is not efficient to create rows like that, there is effectively no way around it. BTW, worksheets often contain many thousands of rows, so I don't exactly understand your reservations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create one row for each header, and populate the first cell in each!

Something like:

```
String[] headers = new String[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3" };

Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("EDR Raw Data");

for (int rn=0; rn<headers.length; rn++) {
   Row r = sheet.createRow(rn);
   r.createCell(0).setCellValue(headers[rn]);
}
```

Then when populating your data, do `sheet.getRow(rownumber)` to get the existing row, and populate the remaining cells of interest in it

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought to do in the same way. But in my case I have 100+ row labels. So is there any other way?

Comment: `.xls` is limited to 65k rows, `.xlsx` rather more, so no issue with doing that for just a few hundred!

Comment: Ok then. I will follow the approach given by you. :)

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks.