# Update Excel file using Java(Insert Row)

Tags: java, excel, file, auto-update

I am trying to update excel file using java.

We have multiple servers whose health i.e. disk space need to be checked every Friday by logging into those servers and check size and also delete some files which are older than month.. and then fill into excel about disk space and then log off.

But now I am trying to automate the tasking using Java.
I successfully checked disk size and deleted files which are older than a month also put that data into excel files.

```
public class UpdateExcel 
     {
        public static void main(String[]args) throws 
EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException
        {
        File f=new File("D:\\TestDeleteFiles");
        String list[]=f.list();
        Calendar lCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        lCal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30); 
        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(list[i]);
                File tmpFile=new File("D:\\TestDeleteFiles\\"+list[i]);
                Date date=new Date(tmpFile.lastModified());
                if(date.before(lCal.getTime()))
            {
                    tmpFile.delete();
                    System.out.println("Deleted");
            }
           }
        try {
            FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
            File[] drives = File.listRoots();

             File cDrive = new File("C:\\");
             File dDrive = new File("D:\\");

                    System.out.println("Drives are : " +cDrive);
                    System.out.println("Drives are : " +dDrive);

                    long cTotSpace = cDrive.getTotalSpace();
                    long cFrSpace = cDrive.getFreeSpace();              
                    long cTotalSpace;
                    long cFreeSpace;

                    long dTotSpace = dDrive.getTotalSpace();
                    long dFrSpace = dDrive.getFreeSpace();              
                    long dTotalSpace;
                    long dFreeSpace;

                    cTotalSpace = cTotSpace / (1024*1024*1024);
                    cFreeSpace = cFrSpace / (1024*1024*1024);

                    dTotalSpace = dTotSpace / (1024*1024*1024);
                    dFreeSpace = dFrSpace / (1024*1024*1024);

                    System.out.println("Total Space in Gb : " + cTotalSpace + " GB");
                    System.out.println("Free Space in Gb : " + cFreeSpace + " GB");

                    System.out.println("Total Space in Gb : " + dTotalSpace + " GB");
                    System.out.println("Free Space in Gb : " + dFreeSpace + " GB");

            String excelFilePath = "D:\\CreateXls\\ServerTestDemo.xls";
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {   
                Row currentRow = iterator.next();

                Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(currentRow.getLastCellNum(), CellType.STRING);
                Cell dcell = currentRow.createCell(currentRow.getLastCellNum(), CellType.STRING);
                Cell cell1 = currentRow.createCell(currentRow.getLastCellNum(), CellType.STRING);
                System.out.println("Hello" + currentRow.getRowNum());
                if(currentRow.getRowNum() == 0)
                    System.out.println("Hello" + currentRow.getRowNum());
                    cell.setCellValue(cFreeSpace);
                    dcell.setCellValue(dFreeSpace);
                    cell1.setCellValue("");                     
            }
            inputStream.close();     
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new 
FileOutputStream("D:\\CreateXls\\ServerTestDemo.xls");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException
                | InvalidFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}   
}
```

This code is working well to put disk size in Excel file..This pic will tell you

[image]

But now What i want to do is to put Labels like server name on 1st row above IP address as well as Dates on basis of when that code will be executed and C or D drives above that Free space.

Well I tried but cause of Iterator Server name also printed multiple time which i dont want.

---

**NOTE:** For information I am not stuck on how to get date and all Its just I am stuck on how to put Labels in First, Second and Third Row without duplication This is demo that's why i took Same IP Address

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're asking, perhaps if you showed what you want the excel sheet to look like someone could assist you.

Based on your description I'm presuming you want row 1 to have headers, it also appears you are using Apache POI. If that is the case you may want to read this post: [How to add header column in excel using Java Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735173/how-to-add-header-column-in-excel-using-java-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to iterate through the rows for updating values in a row. You can just get the row using its index and update cell values.

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
```

In case the row is null, just create a row and update the cell values.

```
if(row == null)
{
    row = sheet.createRow(0);
}
```